# Django list_display does not work at reverse model

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys, django-admin

Django list_display does not work at reverse model, i want to list_display the title and the production company of two seperated but related tables.

here ist my model.py

```
class ProjectBaseModel(models.Model):
title = models.CharField("Titel", max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
former_title = models.CharField("ehemaliger Titel", max_length=100, blank=True)
title_international = models.CharField(
    "Titel, international", max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, unique=True
)
program_length = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    verbose_name="Länge in Min.", blank=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(300)]
)
   
def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    abstract = True
    ordering = ["title"]


class FeatureFilm(ProjectBaseModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Kinofilm"
        verbose_name_plural = "Kinofilme"


class ProjectCompanySet(models.Model):
featurefilm = models.ForeignKey(
    FeatureFilm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
)
tv_movie = models.ForeignKey(
    TvMovie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
)

production_company = models.ForeignKey(
    CompanyOrBranch,
    related_name="production_company",
    verbose_name="Produktionsfirma",
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

My ***FeatureFilm*** table inherits from the ***ProjectBaseModel*** table. I want to display the ***FeatureFilm*** list in the django backend admin.
In the list I want to show the appropriate name, but I also want to show the field  production_company which is one row of the ProductionCompanySet table, which is a child table related to the FeatureFilm table. the production_company field ist a foreign key to the CompanyOrBranch Table.

Here you can see this table:

```
class CompanyOrBranch(CompanyBaseModel):
name = models.CharField(
    "Firma oder Niederlassung",
    max_length=60,
    blank=False,
)
```

and here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import (
   FeatureFilm,
   TvMovie,
   ProjectCompanySet,
   Vendor,
   StaffList,
   VendorVFX,
   QuoteAndEffort,
)

class ProjectCompanySetInLine(admin.StackedInline):
model = ProjectCompanySet
fields = (
    "production_company",
    "co_production",
    "distributor",
    "broadcast",
    "world_sales",
)
classes = ["collapse"]
extra = 0


class FeatureFilmAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
inlines = [
    QuoteAndEffortSetInLine,
    ProjectCompanySetInLine,
    VendorVFXSetInLine,
    VendorSetInLine,
    StaffListSetInLine,
]
list_display = ["title", "projectcompanyset__production_company", ]
```

Comment: It makes no sense to include that in the `list_display`, since there can be zero, one or more of such companies.

Comment: yes I know, I only wanted to display the first of the saved companies

Answer (score 0):

My question was not precise enough. Yes, the FeatureFilm table points with a Foreignkey to a ProjectCompanySet table. and this has a field: production_company. what I actually want is that the first ProjectCompanySet entry and from it the first company is shown to me. What I have managed in the meantime is that the **str** fuction of the ProjectCompany is displayed to me. But if I have several ProjectCompanySet tables then also then several times. But I want only the first ! and then also the string of the production_company. that I have not yet managed.
here my so far extended code:

```
class FeatureFilmAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
inlines = [
    QuoteAndEffortSetInLine,
    ProjectCompanySetInLine,
    VendorVFXSetInLine,
    VendorSetInLine,
    StaffListSetInLine,
]
list_display = ["title", "program_length", "get_company_set"]

def get_company_set(self, Featurefilm):
    return FeatureFilm.objects.filter(pk=Featurefilm.id).values(
        "projectcompanyset__production_company__name"
    )
```